# Calling callback function upon successful sharing in Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to click Facebook share button, then callback a function.

I try all where I find the code from web. I have no APP ID.

My current code:

```
<div class="share_item"><div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id))
                return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.google.com" data-layout="button_count"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no callback for the Share button. You could however use `FB.ui` to call the Share _dialog_ instead – that method takes a callback function. (But I think you might need to use an app id for that. In any case, you _should_ use one.)

Comment: I have try to  use FB.ui to call the Share dialog,it will show dialog when I open this website.I want to click share button ,then show the dialog.

Comment: Create your own button, and call `FB.ui` when the user clicks on that …